# Condition for reflection of wave on a boundary

Tags: waves, reflection

Suppose a wave is travelling from right to left on x-axis. It satisfies $\Box \phi (x,t) =0$. Now I want this wave to get totally reflected at x=0. So what condition do I have to apply on $\phi (x,t)$ so that I get 100% reflection. The answer to this condition is supposed to be $\phi (x=0,t)=0$. But I can't figure why is it so? Nor can I come up with any argument to refute conditions like $\partial _x \phi (x=0,t)=0$, $\partial _t \phi (x=0,t)=0$, $\partial _{xt} \phi (x=0,t)=0$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

An argument explaining why *vanishing boundary conditions* give rise to the *total reflection* of the wavepacket from the boundaries is as follows.

This argument is actually used to prove the existence of the solution under Dirichlet boundary conditions.

First consider the solution of $\square  \phi(x,t)=0$ on the spatial segment $[-L,L]$ with *periodic boundary conditions* and for given *initial conditions* satisfying the same constraint.

This problem can be completely solved (proving an existence and uniqueness theorem if $\phi$ is supposed to be a bit more regular than  $C^2([-L,L]\times \mathbb{R})$) using Fourier analysis, expanding the initial conditions and the solution in Fourier series. The solution turns out to be spatially periodic.  As a matter of fact,
the general solution is made of a couple of independent packets rigidly moving along the opposite directions:  $\Phi(x,t)= f(x+t)+ g(x-t)$.

Now we come back to the problem we are actually interested in, i.e., the solution of $\square \phi=0$ on the spatial segment $[0,L]$ and assuming vanishing boundary conditions at $\pm L$, i.e. $\phi(0)=\phi(L) =0$ (obviously supposing that the initial conditions $\phi(x,0)$ and $\partial_t \phi(x,0)$ satisfy the same boundary constraint).

It is not difficult to prove that the solution can be obtained as follows.

(1) Consider the doubled spatial domain $[-L,L] = [-L,0] \cup [0,L]$,

(2) Define a new field $\Phi(x,t)$ on that enlarged  domain which is the *odd extension* of $\phi$:
$$\Phi(x,t) := \phi(x,t) \quad \mbox{if $x\in [0,L]$, }\qquad \Phi(x,t) := -\phi(-x,t) \quad \mbox{if $x\in [-L,0]$,}$$

(3) Analogously extend the initial conditions of $\phi$ to corresponding initial conditions of $\Phi$.

It is not difficult to see that the problem  $\square \Phi(x,t)=0$ on $[-L,L] \times \mathbb{R}$ with the condition above is a problem with *periodic boundary conditions* over $[-L,L]$.

It therefore  admits a unique solution as we said above. The half solution $\phi(x,t)=\Phi(t,x)|_{x \in [0,L]}$ is the solution of the original problem with *vanishing boundary conditions* on $[0,L]$.

It is now easy to figure out the form of the solution. Let us start with an initial packed $\phi(x,t)$ (and its time derivative) in $[0,L]$ concentrated far from the boundaries and moving towards $L$ (this is imposed by suitably fixing $\partial_t\phi(x,0))$.

Extend this packed on $[-L,0]$ as $-\psi(-x,0)$ and do the same for the other initial condition. Since we have this way reversed the sign of the time derivative of the initial datum in the segment $[-L,0]$, the packet in $[-L,0]$ will move towards $-L$ instead of $L$.

If thinking of the problem as a *periodic problem on $[-L,L]$*, everything is known: You have two packets, one in $[0,L]$ moving towards $L$ and another in $[-L,0]$ moving towards $-L$. The latter has a shape identical to the former up to the sign.

Since the extended problem is periodic in $[-L,L]$, when the packets reach the respective boundaries $\pm L$, they pass through them and pop out from the opposite side $\mp L$. In practice, restricting our attention to what happens in $[0,L]$ (where the original problem with vanishing boundary conditions is discussed), we see that, after  the packet has reached the boundary at $L$,  another packet appears around the same boundary moving towards $0$. This outgoing packet is identical to the ingoing one up to the sign. The net effect is a total reflecion of the ingoing packet from the boundary at $L$.